# Does scientific experience matter for a funded PhD application?

Tags: phd, funding, eu

I have some scientific experience, some papers in conference journals with impact factor, and a couple of papers in scientific journals. I am in a bad situation and may be unable to keep my current PhD (I am a final year student without funding).

I would like to know if I have good changes to be accepted in a funded PhD program in my field of research in another University in EU because of my research experience, or do only the BSc, MSc grades really matter? Mine are not too high. Also, do the MPhil grades also matter for application to a funded PhD program? Mine are high. People aren't supposed to have one when they apply.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, and this is not always the case, publications matter and they matter because they show prior research which helps in situations of lower grades.

However, do be prepared to receive questions in either the interview phase or via email when discussing with the university you will be applying to on why you are leaving in your last year. If your current advisor is in knowledge of your current situation and is willing to recommend you then this may not be a problem at the end.

Hope this helps...